# Sequence for Pre-order traversal of Binary Trees

Tags: algorithm, tree, swift, iterator

I wanted to make a `Sequence` that can do a pre-order traversal of Binary Tree. Doing so provides automatically unlocks wonderfully useful methods, like `prefix`, `map`, `filter`, etc. But doing so requires implementing an Iterator, which conforms to `IteratorProtocol`.

Implementing `next()` to vend elements means that the usual simple recursive solutions aren't possible (because Swift doesn't have continuations, you have no way of "suspending" your recursion until the next call to `next()`).  This is my best attempt. It's working and gives the correct answers, but I would love some feedback.

Here's my primary Binary Tree data structure (note the absence of `parent` references):

```
//=== BinaryTreeNode.swift

public final class BinaryTreeNode<T>: BinaryTreeNodeProtocol {
    public let payload: T
    public let left: BinaryTreeNode<T>?
    public let right: BinaryTreeNode<T>?

    init(
        _ payload: T,
        _ left: BinaryTreeNode<T>? = nil,
        _ right: BinaryTreeNode<T>? = nil
        ) {
        self.payload = payload
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    }
}
```

To allow this iterator to be used in more cases, I extracted out the binary-freeness into a protocol. For example, UIViews could be made to conform, without requiring people to reproduce portions of their view hierarchy into my `BinaryTreeNode` objects.

```
//=== BinaryTreeNodeProtocol.swift

public protocol BinaryTreeNodeProtocol {
    associatedtype Payload
    var payload: Payload { get }
    var left: Self? { get }
    var right: Self? { get }
}
```

Here's the `Sequence`/`Iterator` implementation:

```
//=== BinaryPreorderIterator.swift

public extension BinaryTreeNodeProtocol {
    var preorderTraversal: BinaryTreePreorderSequence<Self> { return BinaryTreePreorderSequence(self) }
}

public struct BinaryTreePreorderSequence<Tree: BinaryTreeNodeProtocol>: Sequence {
    private let tree: Tree

    public init(_ tree: Tree) { self.tree = tree }

    public func makeIterator() -> BinaryPreorderIterator<Tree> {
        return BinaryPreorderIterator(tree: self.tree)
    }
}

public struct BinaryPreorderIterator<Tree: BinaryTreeNodeProtocol>: IteratorProtocol {
    private var backtrackStack: [(node: Tree, nextAction: NextAction)]

    private enum NextAction { case visitRoot, visitLeft, visitRight, returnToParent }

    public init(tree: Tree) {
        backtrackStack = [(tree, .visitRoot)]
    }

    public mutating func next() -> Tree.Payload? {
        // Using a non-constant boolean expression circumvent's the compilers warnings about the value always being false.
        let debugPrinting = Bool("false")!

        if debugPrinting { print("next()") }

        while let popped = backtrackStack.last {

            if debugPrinting {
                print("\tloop - backtrackStack:")
                for (node, nextAction) in backtrackStack.dropLast() {
                    print("\t\t| \(node.payload) \(nextAction)")
                }
                print("\t\t↳ \(popped.node.payload) \(popped.nextAction) <--- current state\n")
            }

            advanceState()

            switch (popped.nextAction) {
            case .visitRoot:
                let returnValue = popped.node.payload
                if debugPrinting { print("\treturning \(returnValue)\n") }
                return returnValue

            case .visitLeft:
                // This block could be more nicely expressed as the following code,
                // but that doesn't work, because the second method call is unconditional,
                // unlike an if/else-if pair.
                //
                // tryMarkingLeftToVisitNext()
                // tryMarkingRightToVisitNext()

                if let leftChild = lastState().node.left {
                    self.visitNext(leftChild)
                }
                else if let rightChild = lastState().node.right {
                    self.visitNext(rightChild)
                }

            case .visitRight:
                tryMarkingRightToVisitNext()

            case .returnToParent:
                break
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

    private func assertLastStateExists() {
        precondition(!backtrackStack.isEmpty, """
        lastState() should only be called when there IS a last state, i.e. the backtrace stack isn't empty.
        """)
    }

    private func lastState() -> (node: Tree, nextAction: NextAction) {
        assertLastStateExists()
        return backtrackStack.last!
    }

    private mutating func setNextActionOnLastNode(_ newNextAction: NextAction) {
        assertLastStateExists()
        backtrackStack[backtrackStack.count - 1].nextAction = newNextAction // gross, but Array.last is write-only
    }

    private mutating func advanceState() {
        switch lastState().nextAction {
        case .visitRoot:  setNextActionOnLastNode(.visitLeft)
        case .visitLeft:  setNextActionOnLastNode(.visitRight)
        case .visitRight: setNextActionOnLastNode(.returnToParent)
        case .returnToParent: backtrackStack.removeLast()
        }
    }

    private mutating func tryMarkingLeftToVisitNext() {
        if let leftChild = lastState().node.left {
            self.visitNext(leftChild)
        }
    }

    private mutating func tryMarkingRightToVisitNext() {
        if let rightChild = lastState().node.right {
            self.visitNext(rightChild)
        }
    }

    private mutating func visitNext(_ node: Tree) {
        backtrackStack.append((node: node, nextAction: .visitRoot))
    }
}
```

And here's a little demo:

```
func sampleTree() -> BinaryTreeNode<Int> {
    typealias B = BinaryTreeNode

    //      4
    //    /   \
    //   2     6
    //  / \   / \
    // 1   3 5   7
    return B(4, B(2, B(1), B(3)), B(6, B(5), B(7)))
}

print(Array(sampleTree().preorderTraversal))
```

Questions:

1. Is there a way to extract the `if`/`else if` pair into calls to `tryMarkingLeftToVisitNext()`/`tryMarkingRightToVisitNext()`? Obviously they could be wrapped in the same `if`/`else if` pair, but that doesn't really tidy anything.
2. I have a strong suspition that one of the `NextAction` states can be removed entirely.

   For example, if elements' payloads were returned upon visiting them, they could be added to the backtrace with a next state of `visitLeft`, omitting the need for `visitRoot` (merely existing in the backtrace implies `visitRoot` was already done).

   I was close to getting this going, but faced issues with how to visit the root (since my backtrace is initialized to `[(tree, .visitRoot)]`, to kick things off on the first call to `next()`). I could only achieve it if I added a separate `root` instance variable to my iterator, and a special case in `next()` branch to handle the root.

All other feedback and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a bug: If a node has a right but no left child then the right subtree is traversed twice. As an example, the tree

```
//      1
//        \
//         2
//        / \
//       3   4
return B(1, nil, B(2, B(3), B(4)))
```

produces the output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

The reason is that for the (empty) left child of node ①, the right child node ② is added twice to the stack, in `func advanceState()` at

```
case .visitLeft:  setNextActionOnLastNode(.visitRight)
```

and in the “main loop” at

```
else if let rightChild = lastState().node.right {
    self.visitNext(rightChild)
}
```

The solution is simple: Remove that else case in `case .visitLeft:`. Which means that you call just `tryMarkingLeftToVisitNext()`, as intended:

```
        case .visitLeft:
            tryMarkingLeftToVisitNext()

        case .visitRight:
            tryMarkingRightToVisitNext()
```

or inline those two functions, since each of them is called only once.

---

What I don't like is how the stack is treated in the main loop:

```
while let popped = backtrackStack.last {
    advanceState()
    switch (popped.nextAction) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The variable name `popped` suggests that the element is *removed* from the stack, but it isn't: It remains on the stack and is mutated or removed in `func advanceState()`.

I would also suggest to have a single place where the current state is acted upon, not two places (which can cause subtle bugs, as we saw above).

The main loop then would look like this

```
while let popped = backtrackStack.popLast() {
    switch (popped.nextAction) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

where the switch handles the different cases, and appends new states to the stack where necessary. This

- simplifies the code and the logic,
- makes various utility functions obsolete,
- makes the `.removeToParent` case obsolete,
- makes the forced unwrapping in `last!` and the checks for a non-empty stack obsolete at various places.

This leads to the following implementation of `struct BinaryPreorderIterator`:

```
public struct BinaryPreorderIterator<Tree: BinaryTreeNodeProtocol>: IteratorProtocol {
    private var backtrackStack: [(node: Tree, nextAction: NextAction)]
    private enum NextAction { case visitRoot, visitLeft, visitRight }

    public init(tree: Tree) {
        backtrackStack = [(tree, .visitRoot)]
    }

    public mutating func next() -> Tree.Payload? {
        while let popped = backtrackStack.popLast() {
            switch (popped.nextAction) {
            case .visitRoot:
                backtrackStack.append((popped.node, .visitLeft))
                return popped.node.payload

            case .visitLeft:
                backtrackStack.append((popped.node, .visitRight))
                if let leftChild = popped.node.left {
                    backtrackStack.append((leftChild, .visitRoot))
                }

            case .visitRight:
                if let rightChild = popped.node.right {
                    backtrackStack.append((rightChild, .visitRoot))
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

---

And now we see that the stack actually just identifies the nodes which have to be visited later. If we push left and right child nodes onto the stack immediately when a node is encountered then the `enum NextAction` and the while-loop are not needed anymore:

```
public struct BinaryPreorderIterator<Tree: BinaryTreeNodeProtocol>: IteratorProtocol {
    private var backtrackStack: [Tree]

    public init(tree: Tree) {
        backtrackStack = [tree]
    }

    public mutating func next() -> Tree.Payload? {
        guard let node = backtrackStack.popLast() else {
            return nil // Stack is empty.
        }
        if let rightChild = node.right {
            backtrackStack.append(rightChild)
        }
        if let leftChild = node.left {
            backtrackStack.append(leftChild)
        }
        return node.payload
    }
}
```

Note that we have reduced the implementation of `struct BinaryPreorderIterator` from 75 lines to 20 lines (not counting the debug output) and simplified it considerably. It also takes less memory and is more efficient.

*Remark:* `func next()`could be more compactly written using `Optional.map`:

```
    public mutating func next() -> Tree.Payload? {
        guard let node = backtrackStack.popLast() else {
            return nil
        }
        node.left.map { backtrackStack.append($0) }
        node.right.map { backtrackStack.append($0) }
        return node.payload
    }
```

or even

```
    public mutating func next() -> Tree.Payload? {
        return backtrackStack.popLast().map { node in
            node.left.map { backtrackStack.append($0) }
            node.right.map { backtrackStack.append($0) }
            return node.payload
        }
    }
```

but that does not make it better readable or understandable.

---

Some further suggestions:

It suffices to implement the `IteratorProtocol` protocol and to *declare* the `Sequence` conformance, making `struct BinaryTreePreorderSequence` obsolete:

```
public extension BinaryTreeNodeProtocol {
    var preorderTraversal: BinaryPreorderIterator<Self> {
        return BinaryPreorderIterator(tree: self) }
}

public struct BinaryPreorderIterator<Tree: BinaryTreeNodeProtocol>: IteratorProtocol, Sequence {
    private var backtrackStack: [Tree]

    public init(tree: Tree) {
        backtrackStack = [tree]
    }

    public mutating func next() -> Tree.Payload? {
        guard let node = backtrackStack.popLast() else {
            return nil
        }
        if let rightChild = node.right {
            backtrackStack.append(rightChild)
        }
        if let leftChild = node.left {
            backtrackStack.append(leftChild)
        }
        return node.payload
    }
}
```

This works because there is a default implementation of `func makeIterator()` for `IteratorProtocol`.

Finally, I would *not* use empty argument labels in the init method of `class BinaryTreeNode`:

```
public final class BinaryTreeNode<T>: BinaryTreeNodeProtocol {
    // ...

    init(
        _ payload: T,
        left: BinaryTreeNode<T>? = nil,
        right: BinaryTreeNode<T>? = nil
        ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This requires more typing, but may be easier to read, and allows to create nodes with a right subtree only, without having to use a `nil` argument for the left subtree:

```
B(1, right: B(2, left: B(3), right: B(4)))
// versus
B(1, nil, B(2, B(3), B(4)))
```

Comment: Wow, this is *much* more improved than I was expecting! I wasn't thrilled about the `while let popped = backtrackStack.last` part either, but I found myself re-appending the elements I just popped off, so I changed to this "peek" approach instead but forgot to rename the `popped` variable. (Boy I wish we just had a simple stack with nice `peek()`/`push()`/`pop()` operations)

Comment: I understand the removal of `if let rightChild = popped.node.right` under the `.visitLeft` case (since its absence just caused another loop around, this time reaching the `.visitRight` state because of the `advance()` call from the previous loop). I'm a little confused about how you were able to remove the need for the loop, but part of the problem there was that I don't remember the problem that the loop initially solved lol. I'll think on it!

Comment: I have mixed feelings about conforming to both `IteratorProtocol` and `Sequence`. I knew it was possible, but I thought you would need to add a `makeIterator()` implementation that just does `return self`. Didn't know that the standard library adds that by default, so that serves as a kind of "endorsement". But I still don't like the idea of making one-shot sequences where it's not strictly necessary, even if making a separate `Sequence` requires this extra boilerplate

Comment: Think you so much for your time Martin, I appreciate it. I'll work over this and let you know if I have any follow up questions :)

Comment: Suppose the binary tree nodes had parent references, it wouldn't be possible to do any better, space-wise, right? Intuitively that makes sense to me, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Alexander: I think you would still need a stack to remember in which direction to move from a parent node: to the next parent or to the right child.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thinking too.

Comment: @Alexander: Thinking about it again: My last comment is probably wrong, because every node has a *unique* successor in the traversal. When you return from a node to its parent node then you can compare this node to the parent's left and right child, and decide where to continue.

Comment: @Alexander: But this would not save *memory* because you had a parent pointer in each node. The stack becomes only as large as the tree's height.